# Lore vs Knowledge

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have a question about lore vs knowledge. When I translate `lore` to my language it has meaning as `knowledge`. But when I check at thesaurus.com, lore has synonyms such as mythology, legend, etc. Also, lore is usually used in the context of gaming, movie, or novel. But can we use lore in the context of something that is "scientific" matter? For example, I write a book with the title 'Physics Lore' and it talks purely about physics. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Physics Lore" doesn't really give the right sense.  "Lore" is the traditions and stories surrounding a topic, not scientific facts.

So "Physics lore" would include the stories of how Galileo dropped weights of the Tower of Pisa, Newton was hit by an apple, or Einstein asked if "Oxford stopped at the train". It would contain traditions like "five sigma is needed for a discovery" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

***Lore*** means:

> a body of *traditions* and knowledge on a subject or held by a particular group, ***typically passed from person to person by word of mouth***. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=lore%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsabChoIH0goPEyf0VwtDaSwdQA53g%3A1660976208253&ei=UHwAY5GJD8Ww8gLHpJioAQ&oq=lore%20&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYATIECAAQQzILCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEyCAgAEIAEELEDMgsILhCABBDHARCvATILCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEyBQgAEIAEMgsILhCABBCxAxDUAjILCC4QgAQQxwEQ0QMyBQguEIAEMgUIABCABDoICC4Q1AIQkQI6BQgAEJECOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoICC4QsQMQgwE6CwguEIAEELEDEIMBOgQIABADOg4ILhCABBCxAxCDARDUAjoECCMQJzoKCC4QxwEQ0QMQQzoECC4QQzoRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQrwE6CAguEIAEELEDOg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARDRA0oECEEYAUoECEYYAFCDG1iYI2D_MWgBcAB4AIABfYgB2AOSAQMzLjKYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz))

So no, that would not apply to the science of Physics. To better understand the use of *lore*, it might help to mention that it is part of the word ***folklore***:

> "traditional beliefs and customs of the common people," 1846, coined by antiquarian William J. Thoms (1803-1885) as an Anglo-Saxonism (replacing *popular antiquities*) in imitation of German compounds in Volk- and first published in the Athenaeum of Aug. 22, 1846; see ***folk*** + ***lore***. ([etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/folklore))